# Is it possible to pass a string variable as a file in command line argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm invoking a command line child process that converts a local file to another file format. It goes like this

```
>myFileConversion localfile.txt convertedfile.bin
```

That would convert the localfile.txt to the needed format in a file named convertedfile.bin. 
It also has an option to put the contents in stdout. 
I'm running this in node js on the server and need the create the localfile.txt on the fly.

The contents of localfile.txt is just a string I dynamically generate. **If possible, I would like the pass the string instead of writing the string to a file to be more efficient.** How could I do this? Is it possible? Would it be faster than just writing to the local file?

Comment: That above command is *already* passing two strings to the process; the difference is just that the process then proceeds to treat these strings as filenames and attempts to open them.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes, to be more specific, I mean I would like to pass a variable name that contains the contents of the file instead of the filename.

Comment: Oh, I see. You can't do that. The other process has no way of resolving the variable to its contents; to it, it's just a word. If the other process were acting like a server, i.e. already running and listening for input, you could pipe data to it directly. But if the conversion is a single operation, just keep using the file.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned in the comments it may be possible to pipe the data but since I only need to save the file once, it's easier to just save the file locally and pass the name of the file. 
Please post other possible answers as well!